# SSL with Amazon EC2 is invalid

Tags: ssl

I purchased an SSL certificate from Comodo and have followed their (terrible) setup instructions.

I'm confident I have all the files in the right places, but browsers are still giving an error.

When I try to go on https://www.roryholland.co.uk it says the certificate is only valid for ip-10-112-47-5.ec2.internal (a dynamic Amazon IP), although I do have a static "elastic" IP set up.

Do I have to reissue the certificate?

Answer (score 3):

Well, in addition to having the wrong domain, the cert presented has not been signed by a trusted CA.

You're still likely using the self-signed cert that shipped with the distro. You need to verify that your purchased cert has been installed correctly.

Comment: Also, make sure when you are generating the cert, you use the proper domain name and not xxxx.ec2.internal.

Comment: In the virtualhost section in httpd.conf I'm specifying the correct certificate file

Comment: Well then you need to ensure that the correct virtual host is catching these requests.

Comment: `grep -r -i ssl /etc/httpd/*` or whatever to see all the SSL configurations

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like when you created the CSR.. you setup the CN wrong.. You set it to the hostname on the server and not www.roryholland.co.uk